# Insertion in std::vector vs. insertion in std::deque

Tags: c++, vector, deque

I was solving the puzzles in [2017 Advent of Code](http://adventofcode.com/2017/day/17). It was necessary to fill in circular buffer using certain algorithm. For the buffer implementation I first used vector, and then I tried with deque. I am getting different results when printing values of the vector and the queue. Here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

void PrintBuffer(std::vector<int> a_CircularBuffer)
{
    for (std::vector<int>::iterator it = a_CircularBuffer.begin(); it != a_CircularBuffer.end(); ++it) {
        std::cout << *it << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> circularBuffer;
    circularBuffer.reserve(20);

    circularBuffer.push_back(0);
    circularBuffer.push_back(1);

    std::vector<int>::iterator currentPosition = circularBuffer.begin() + 1;

    for (int i = 2; i < 20; ++i) {
        int steps = 378;
        if (steps >= i) {
            steps = (steps % i);
        }    

        if ((circularBuffer.end() - currentPosition) <= steps) {
            currentPosition = circularBuffer.begin() + (((currentPosition - circularBuffer.begin()) + steps) % i);
            circularBuffer.insert(currentPosition, i);
        }
        else {
            currentPosition = currentPosition + steps;
            circularBuffer.insert(currentPosition, i);
        }
        PrintBuffer(circularBuffer);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This is the result when using vector:

```
0 2 1
0 3 2 1 
0 3 2 4 1 
0 5 3 2 4 1 
0 6 5 3 2 4 1 
0 7 6 5 3 2 4 1 
0 7 6 8 5 3 2 4 1 
0 7 6 9 8 5 3 2 4 1 
0 10 7 6 9 8 5 3 2 4 1 
0 10 7 6 9 11 8 5 3 2 4 1 
0 10 7 6 9 11 8 5 3 2 4 12 1 
0 10 7 6 9 11 8 5 3 2 4 12 13 1 
0 10 7 6 9 11 8 5 3 2 4 12 14 13 1 
15 0 10 7 6 9 11 8 5 3 2 4 12 14 13 1 
...
```

and this is when using deque (just change "vector" to "deque" and comment out circularBuffer.reserve(20) line):

```
0 2 1 
0 3 2 1 
0 3 2 4 1 
0 5 3 2 4 1 
0 5 6 3 2 4 1 
0 5 6 7 3 2 4 1 
0 5 6 7 3 8 2 4 1 
0 5 6 7 3 9 8 2 4 1 
0 5 6 10 7 3 9 8 2 4 1 
0 5 6 10 7 3 9 8 11 2 4 1 
0 5 12 6 10 7 3 9 8 11 2 4 1 
0 5 12 6 13 10 7 3 9 8 11 2 4 1 
0 5 12 6 13 14 10 7 3 9 8 11 2 4 1 
0 5 12 6 13 14 10 7 3 15 9 8 11 2 4 1
...
```

Why there are different results for vector and deque?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get undefined behaviour when you insert an element causing reallocation, and then use the old iterator again.

Anything can happen.

Use index to store current position and it'll work the same way.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, later I was using index to store current position and it worked the same way as with the deque and iterators. I was just wandering why with vector is different, I didn't know it is an undefined behavior. Also, when I do something like this currentPosition = circularBuffer.insert(currentPosition, i), I am getting the same result as before. I thought this will "renew" currentPosition iterator.

Comment: One more thing, if I reserved enough space (and I did), there should be no reallocation, right? Then iterators should be OK, i guess?

Comment: for deque it's UB even if there's no reallocation > If the insertion happens at the beginning or the end of the sequence, all iterators related to this container are invalidated, but pointers and references remain valid, referring to the same elements they were referring to before the call.
If the insertion happens anywhere else in the deque, all iterators, pointers and references related to this container are invalidated.